# Django HTTP requests fail on Heroku but not locally

Tags: django, http, heroku, request

I have this Django project and there's a function in it that executes a for loop with a HTTP request for every iteration.
Locally everything's fine but on Heroku if the iterations are more than 2 or 3 it fails.
I'm wondering if Heroku blocks too many outgoing requests and if there's a workaround. Thanks!

Comment: How can any one tell without looking at the error log?